# Server response message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to get server response error message to show in form after submit. I get message if i use this code in js

```
 .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    $scope.postDataSuccessfully = false;
    var messages = [];
    angular.forEach(data.errors, function (value, key) {
        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;
        messages.push('Error! ' + key + ' is not correct');

    });
    $scope.messages = messages;
});
```

and in html

```
 <div ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">
    <div data-ng-hide="message == ''" data-ng-class="(postDataSuccessfully) ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'">
        {{message}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

but this is only shown on one place after submit, like on this image
[image]

I want to have message on field with error, like on next image
[image]

Here is my html code for this form input

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{'TYPE'| translate}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" ng-model="type">
      <option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
    </select>


  </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{'DESCRIPTION'| translate}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" ng-model="description" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two options : 
either you put for each field an error message and display it when it occur

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.myselect.$error"  ng-if="myForm.$submitted || myForm.myselect.$touched">
 <div ng-message="required">myselect is required.</div>
</div>
```

or alternatively you can use the toast popup error msgs :

```
$scope.validateMyData = function() {
      var errorType = callYourServerService();

    if(errorType === "myFirstField") {
      toaster.pop('error', "Error", "Please insert valid value for myFirstField");
    }
     if(errorType === "mySecondField") {
      toaster.pop('error', "Error", "Please insert valid value for mySecondField");
    }
```

... etc

Comment: hi, thnx for response. i try this, but not working, I try with toaster. Added script and css. Call on submit validateMyData(), and added all errorType, but there is any notification.

Comment: you can follow one of the demos : 
using Angular Material : 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast
....
Or using Angular with Bootsrap
https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster


hope this helps 
regards

Comment: i dont know what i missed, but i do everything like on tutotial, and always get type error when call toaster. "typeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined"

Comment: make sure you have module dependency : 'toaster', in your angular  app module definition ....

also in your controller include the 'toaster' dependency ...

and also in the main HTML don't forget to include 

<toaster-container></toaster-container> ...

Comment: hi, i add everything... and also try different tutorials and forums, but still dont work. I do this with ng-messages on frontend. And in footer of form show all server response. I know this is not the best solution, but for now is ok. If u have any new idea feel free to post here. Thnx

Comment: please provide your code via jsfiddle or any other code sharing, at least the angular controller and the html template

Comment: Thnx, i changed this code for use with ng-message. I can only show this code now, if this can help?